# Error while using post in Postman

Tags: c#, post, postman

I am trying to pass raw data in JSON format using Post method and store it in class which is having properties but is showing error. 
My code in Value Controller-

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void AddEmployee()
    {
        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest`= (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:50278/api/values/AddEmployee");

        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    ////////Above line is giving error///////

    Stream receiveStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Models.Employee));
    Models.Employee user = (Models.Employee)serializer.ReadObject(receiveStream);


    }
```

Class Where I want to store my data in

```
Models.Employee
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string MiddleName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
     public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOJ { get; set; }
     public Nullable<short> IsActivce { get; set; }
}
```

Command which i passed in Postman Post http://localhost:50278/api/values/AddEmployee

with data

```
[
{   
"FirstName" : "ABDCD",
"MiddleName" :"sajsoa",
"LastName"  : "KSJFHF",
"DOB":1994-01-12 00:00:00.0001994-01-12 00:00:00.000,
"DOJ":1994-01-12 00:00:00.0001994-01-12 00:00:00.000,
"Isactive" : 1
}
]
```

I received the below error:
 `System.Net.WebException` occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code. 
Additional information:

```
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

Can you please tell why is it showing error and whether the date format is correct?

Comment: please post the error message you are getting

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Why you sending request recursively?

Comment: Because your request send using `GET` method by default. But your `AddEmployee` accept only `POST` requests

Comment: I am sending Post request in Postman and Post request is applied on the Method so where should i edit my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddEmployee([FromBody]Models.Employee user)
{
   EService eserv = new EService();
    eserv.Addemp(user);
}
```

Comment: I tried that too , it's giving this error  ---                                               "Message": "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Employee' from content with media type 'text/plain'.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
  "StackTrace": "  System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type,      I just want Models.Employee to store the data

Comment: It's executed but when i try to access the Models.Employee Emp.FirstName it throws ----     An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in EmployeeService.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Hey thanks it's working :) Have one question what if i want to store data in two Models using one single command like above  if i have              Models.Department { Departmentid {get, set},   Departname{get,set}}  so according to your method                                                            public void AddEmployee([FromBody]Models.Employee user) it will store only of Employee what if i want to include Models.Department too ?

Comment: As long as you send the right properties, the server will correctly map them to the respective objects, so something like  `public void AddEmployee([FromBody]Models.Employee user, [FromBody]Models.Department dept)` should work. Also, please accept this answer if it has solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have added it as Answer but minimum 15 repu is required to display it publicly.